# Android startActivity in BroadcastReceiver's onReceive function

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, broadcast

I have the following code in my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive function.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action == null) return;
    if (action.equals(ACTION_ALARM)) {
        Intent alarmPopup = new Intent(context, AlarmPopup.class);
        int vibrateDuration = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0)
                .getInt(VIBRATE_DURATION, DEFAULT_VIBRATE_DURATION)
        alarmPopup.putExtra(VIBRATE_DURATION, vibrateDuration);
        alarmPopup.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmPopup);
    }
}
```

This code starts activity `AlarmPopup` as it receives alarm manager's broadcast.
Once the AlarmPopup activity is started, it shows a typical alarm message and vibrates during `vibrateDuration` passed through `Intent#putExtra`.

In AlarmPopup's onCreate method, the activity holds `WakeLock` to make the device keep turning on.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wl = getLock(this);
    if (!wl.isHeld()) {
        Log.d(PREF, "Alarm popup acquires wake lock");
        wl.acquire();
        thread.run();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

`getLock` is a synchronized method that manages `WakeLock` as [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) does.

```
private static volatile PowerManager.WakeLock wlStatic = null;

synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (wlStatic == null) {
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wlStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, PREF);
        wlStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }
    return wlStatic;
}
```

Now here is the problem: even though `context.startActivity(alarmPopup)` is called, `startActivity` **rarely** does not start the activitiy or starts not on time, usually 1-2 minutes later.

It seems that OS kills my AlarmPopup activitiy in the middle of its creation or let the activity be created a little bit later than the time when `startActivity` was actually called.

What is really interesting is, when the above problem happens, sometimes the log message `"Alarm popup acquires wake lock"` is recorded and sometimes it is not even recorded. I think, in this case, OS kills the activity while it executes the first or second line of `onCreate` method.

How can I solve this problem?

Should I put some dummy code that holds the CPU at the end of onReceive while the AlarmPopup activity is being created by another thread?

Comment: try after setting `alarmPopup.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND)` in onRecive of BroadcastReciver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that OS kills my AlarmPopup activitiy in the middle of its creation or let the activity be created a little bit later than the time when startActivity was actually called.

No. The device simply fell asleep. `startActivity()` is an asynchronous operation. The `WakeLock` held by the OS for the `AlarmManager` work (assuming that you are, indeed, using `AlarmManager`) will be released when `onReceive()` returns. `onCreate()` of your activity will not have run by the time `onReceive()` returns. Hence, the device might fall asleep in the window of time between the end of `onReceive()` and when you acquire your `WakeLock` in `onCreate()`.

> How can I solve this problem?

Acquire the `WakeLock` in `onReceive()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually when I wrote this question, I hoped you answer to my question, and it really happens! :) So you mean the static wake lock of AlarmPopup should be acquired in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver and released in OnDestroy of AlarmPopup?

Comment: @Heejin: Well, ideally, you do not use a manual `WakeLock` very long for an activity. I would use `android:keepScreenOn` for a widget if you want the screen to stay on while the activity is in the foreground. Regardless, I would `release()` the manual `WakeLock` as soon as possible, ideally well before `onDestroy()`. But, yes, you would `acquire()` it in `onReceive()`.